# After rewrite URL how to catch GET value in php

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I am passing variable id from index.php page to load.php page and on load.php page i want to catch id variable with GET[id];

**index.php**

```
<a href="load?id=1">Click Here</a>
```

**Load.php**

```
echo $_GET['id'];
```

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L] 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /healthgrace/load/?\?id=([^&\ ]+)&?([^\ ]*)
RewriteRule ^ /healthgrace/load/%1?%2 [R=301,L]
```

When i am catching id on load page it will show 500 internal Server Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way with corrected regex in `301` rule:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(healthgrace/load)/?\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/healthgrace/load)/([\w-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.php?id=%2 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```